# Outlook Importing PST File into IMAP account

Tags: email, outlook, imap

I am having an issue with importing my pst file back into my email account. Unfortunately my domain got deleted from my hosting company and I lost my email account as well. Luckily I had the emails on my Outlook as my email was setup as an IMAP account and I managed to back this up before activating the same email address and password.

Once I done that I then tried to import the .pst file back into my inbox and all my folders started showing up. The inbox then gets synchronised and then after 10 mins the folders and everything disappears.

I spoke to the hosting company and they spent 2 hours on a screen share without resolving and told me to get in touch with Microsoft as they think its an Outlook issue.

The file itself is a 1.4Gb file and I tried one folder at a time as well, but this disappears as well. I don't know if its because I had a IMAP account and the mails were actually stored on the server side rather than on my computer. Although I have made a backup and the size tells me its populated, I just don't now how else to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it does not sound like a programming question.

Secondly, try to disconnect your machine from the internet (so that IMAP does not sync), add a new PST store, and copy all folders from the IMAP store to PST.
After you sync the IMAP store, you can drag the folders back from PST to IMAP.